# Using LIDAR in a 360-degree configuration

Tags: radar, lidar, sonar

(I do not know an appropriate place for this on Stack Exchange. There does not appear to be any groups dedicated to LIDAR or ranging, so this will do for now. Please let me know if there is a better place to post this.)

Are there any current technologies that see Lidar being used in 360-degree, long range rangefinding? Radar systems are obviously used for 360-degree, long range rangefinding in aircraft, while sonar systems are still used in submarines for 360-degree environmental sensing. What about Lidar?

[image]

As stereotypical as this image is, this is what I'm wondering whether Lidar is being developed for.

Please let me know if more info is needed to answer this question.

Comment: Just Google “rotating LIDAR”. Lots of examples.

Comment: Fully self driving cars nearly always use 360 degree scanning lidar. Take a look at Waymo, Cruze, or any of the others.

Comment: A lot of robotics applications use 360 degree or 2D lidar